# Cant get what's the issue with Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, smarty, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using smarty template engine. I'm using datepicker js plugin. My HTML code is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="middle" align="right"><b>From Date </b> : </td>
    <td align="left" >&nbsp;<input type="text" style="width:100px;" class="inputfield" name="from_date" id="from_date" value="{$from_date}" maxlength="10"/></td>
    <td valign="middle" align="right"><b>To Date </b> : </td>
    <td>&nbsp;<input type="text" style="width:100px;" class="inputfield" name="to_date" id="to_date" value="{$to_date}" maxlength="10"/></td>
</tr>
```

The jQuery function code is as below :

```
    {literal}
    <script language="javascript" type="application/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $( "#from_date" ).datepicker({ 
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
      });

      $(function() {
        $( "#to_date" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
      });

          $(document).ready(function()  { 
            $("#questions_listing").tablesorter({             
              widgets:['zebra'],
              // sort on the fourth column and first column, order asc 
              sortList: [[1,0]]    
            });                     
          });   

    $(".submit_form").click(function(e) { 
      var result = validateDate();

      if(!result)
        return false;
      else
      document.questions_filter.submit();
    });
    </script>
    {/literal}
```

The datepicker.js file is as follows:

```
/*  $(function() {
        $( "#cal_from_date" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });

    $( "#cal_to_date" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
            }); 

    });*/

var datePickerDivID = "datepicker";
var iFrameDivID = "datepickeriframe";

var dayArrayShort = new Array('Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa');
var dayArrayMed = new Array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
var dayArrayLong = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
var monthArrayShort = new Array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
var monthArrayMed = new Array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
var monthArrayLong = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');

var defaultDateSeparator = "/";        // common values would be "/" or "."
var defaultDateFormat = "dmy"    // valid values are "mdy", "dmy", and "ymd"
var dateSeparator = defaultDateSeparator;
var dateFormat = defaultDateFormat;

function displayDatePicker(dateFieldName, displayBelowThisObject, dtFormat, dtSep)
{ 
  var targetDateField = document.getElementsByName (dateFieldName).item(0);
   if (!displayBelowThisObject)
    displayBelowThisObject = targetDateField;

   if (dtSep)
    dateSeparator = dtSep;
  else
    dateSeparator = defaultDateSeparator;


  if (dtFormat)
    dateFormat = dtFormat;
  else
    dateFormat = defaultDateFormat;

  var x = displayBelowThisObject.offsetLeft;
  var y = displayBelowThisObject.offsetTop + displayBelowThisObject.offsetHeight ;


  var parent = displayBelowThisObject;
  while (parent.offsetParent) {
    parent = parent.offsetParent;
    x += parent.offsetLeft;
    y += parent.offsetTop ;
  }

  drawDatePicker(targetDateField, x, y);
}



function drawDatePicker(targetDateField, x, y)
{
  var dt = getFieldDate(targetDateField.value );

   if (!document.getElementById(datePickerDivID)) {
    // don't use innerHTML to update the body, because it can cause global variables
    // that are currently pointing to objects on the page to have bad references
    //document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='" + datePickerDivID + "' class='dpDiv'></div>";
    var newNode = document.createElement("div");
    newNode.setAttribute("id", datePickerDivID);
    newNode.setAttribute("class", "dpDiv");
    newNode.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;");
    document.body.appendChild(newNode);
  }

  // move the datepicker div to the proper x,y coordinate and toggle the visiblity
  var pickerDiv = document.getElementById(datePickerDivID);
  pickerDiv.style.position = "absolute";
  pickerDiv.style.left = x + "px";
  pickerDiv.style.top = y + "px";
  pickerDiv.style.visibility = (pickerDiv.style.visibility == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible");
  pickerDiv.style.display = (pickerDiv.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block");
  pickerDiv.style.zIndex = 10000;

  // draw the datepicker table
  refreshDatePicker(targetDateField.name, dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());
}


function refreshDatePicker(dateFieldName, year, month, day)
{ 
  var thisDay = new Date();

  if ((month >= 0) && (year > 0)) {
    thisDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
  } else {
    day = thisDay.getDate();
    thisDay.setDate(1);
  }

   var crlf = "\r\n";
  var TABLE = "<table cols=7 class='dpTable'>" + crlf;
  var xTABLE = "</table>" + crlf;
  var TR = "<tr class='dpTR'>";
  var TR_title = "<tr class='dpTitleTR'>";
  var TR_days = "<tr class='dpDayTR'>";
  var TR_todaybutton = "<tr class='dpTodayButtonTR'>";
  var xTR = "</tr>" + crlf;
  var TD = "<td class='dpTD' onMouseOut='this.className=\"dpTD\";' onMouseOver=' this.className=\"dpTDHover\";' ";    
  var TD_title = "<td colspan=5 class='dpTitleTD'>";
  var TD_buttons = "<td class='dpButtonTD'>";
  var TD_todaybutton = "<td colspan=7 class='dpTodayButtonTD'>";
  var TD_days = "<td class='dpDayTD'>";
  var TD_selected = "<td class='dpDayHighlightTD' onMouseOut='this.className=\"dpDayHighlightTD\";' onMouseOver='this.className=\"dpTDHover\";' ";    // leave this tag open, because we'll be adding an onClick event
  var xTD = "</td>" + crlf;
  var DIV_title = "<div class='dpTitleText'>";
  var DIV_selected = "<div class='dpDayHighlight'>";
  var xDIV = "</div>";

  // start generating the code for the calendar table
  var html = TABLE;

  // this is the title bar, which displays the month and the buttons to
  // go back to a previous month or forward to the next month
  html += TR_title;
  html += TD_buttons + getButtonCode(dateFieldName, thisDay, -1, "&lt;") + xTD;
  html += TD_title + DIV_title + monthArrayLong[ thisDay.getMonth()] + " " + thisDay.getFullYear() + xDIV + xTD;
  html += TD_buttons + getButtonCode(dateFieldName, thisDay, 1, "&gt;") + xTD;
  html += xTR;

  // this is the row that indicates which day of the week we're on
  html += TR_days;
  for(i = 0; i < dayArrayShort.length; i++)
    html += TD_days + dayArrayShort[i] + xTD;
  html += xTR;

  // now we'll start populating the table with days of the month
  html += TR;

  // first, the leading blanks
  for (i = 0; i < thisDay.getDay(); i++)
    html += TD + "&nbsp;" + xTD;

  // now, the days of the month
  do {
    dayNum = thisDay.getDate();
    TD_onclick = " onclick=\"updateDateField('" + dateFieldName + "', '" + getDateString(thisDay) + "');\">";

    if (dayNum == day)
      html += TD_selected + TD_onclick + DIV_selected + dayNum + xDIV + xTD;
    else
      html += TD + TD_onclick + dayNum + xTD;

    // if this is a Saturday, start a new row
    if (thisDay.getDay() == 6)
      html += xTR + TR;

    // increment the day
    thisDay.setDate(thisDay.getDate() + 1);
  } while (thisDay.getDate() > 1)

  // fill in any trailing blanks
  if (thisDay.getDay() > 0) {
    for (i = 6; i > thisDay.getDay(); i--)
      html += TD + "&nbsp;" + xTD;
  }
  html += xTR;

  // add a button to allow the user to easily return to today, or close the calendar
  var today = new Date();
  var todayString = "Today is " + dayArrayMed[today.getDay()] + ", " + monthArrayMed[ today.getMonth()] + " " + today.getDate();
  html += TR_todaybutton + TD_todaybutton;
  html += "<button class='dpTodayButton' onClick='refreshDatePicker(\"" + dateFieldName + "\");'>this month</button> ";
  html += "<button class='dpTodayButton' onClick='updateDateField(\"" + dateFieldName + "\");'>close</button>";
  html += xTD + xTR;

  // and finally, close the table
  html += xTABLE;

  document.getElementById(datePickerDivID).innerHTML = html;
  // add an "iFrame shim" to allow the datepicker to display above selection lists
  adjustiFrame();
}


/**
Convenience function for writing the code for the buttons that bring us back or forward
a month.
*/
function getButtonCode(dateFieldName, dateVal, adjust, label) 
{
  var newMonth = (dateVal.getMonth () + adjust) % 12;
  var newYear = dateVal.getFullYear() + parseInt((dateVal.getMonth() + adjust) / 12);
  if (newMonth < 0) {
    newMonth += 12;
    newYear += -1;
  }

  return "<button class='dpButton' onClick='refreshDatePicker(\"" + dateFieldName + "\", " + newYear + ", " + newMonth + ");'>" + label + "</button>";
}


/**
Convert a JavaScript Date object to a string, based on the dateFormat and dateSeparator
variables at the beginning of this script library.
*/
function getDateString(dateVal) 
{
  var dayString = "00" + dateVal.getDate();
  var monthString = "00" + (dateVal.getMonth()+1);
  dayString = dayString.substring(dayString.length - 2);
  monthString = monthString.substring(monthString.length - 2);

  switch (dateFormat) { 
    case "dmy" :
      return dayString + dateSeparator + monthString + dateSeparator + dateVal.getFullYear();
    case "ymd" :
      return dateVal.getFullYear() + dateSeparator + monthString + dateSeparator + dayString;
    case "mdy" :
    default :
      return monthString + dateSeparator + dayString + dateSeparator + dateVal.getFullYear();
  }

}


/**
Convert a string to a JavaScript Date object.
*/
function getFieldDate(dateString) 
{
  var dateVal;
  var dArray;
  var d, m, y;

  try {
    dArray = splitDateString(dateString);
    if (dArray) {
      switch (dateFormat) {
        case "dmy" :
          d = parseInt(dArray[0], 10);
          m = parseInt(dArray[1], 10) - 1;
          y = parseInt(dArray[2], 10);
          break;
        case "ymd" :
          d = parseInt(dArray[2], 10);
          m = parseInt(dArray[1], 10) - 1;
          y = parseInt(dArray[0], 10);
          break;
        case "mdy" :
        default :
          d = parseInt(dArray[1], 10);
          m = parseInt(dArray[0], 10) - 1;
          y = parseInt(dArray[2], 10);
          break;
      }
      dateVal = new Date(y, m, d);
    } else if (dateString) {
      dateVal = new Date(dateString);
    } else {
      dateVal = new Date();
    }
  } catch(e) {
    dateVal = new Date();
  }

  return dateVal;
}



function splitDateString(dateString)
{
  var dArray;
  if (dateString.indexOf("/") >= 0)
    dArray = dateString.split("/");
  else if (dateString.indexOf(".") >= 0)
    dArray = dateString.split(".");
  else if (dateString.indexOf("-") >= 0)
    dArray = dateString.split("-");
  else if (dateString.indexOf("\\") >= 0)
    dArray = dateString.split("\\");
  else
    dArray = false;

  return dArray;
}


function updateDateField(dateFieldName, dateString)
{
  var targetDateField = document.getElementsByName (dateFieldName).item(0);
  if (dateString)
    targetDateField.value = dateString;

  var pickerDiv = document.getElementById(datePickerDivID);
  pickerDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
  pickerDiv.style.display = "none";

  adjustiFrame();
  targetDateField.focus();

  // after the datepicker has closed, optionally run a user-defined function called
  // datePickerClosed, passing the field that was just updated as a parameter
  // (note that this will only run if the user actually selected a date from the datepicker)
  if ((dateString) && (typeof(datePickerClosed) == "function"))
    datePickerClosed(targetDateField);
}



function adjustiFrame(pickerDiv, iFrameDiv)
{
  // we know that Opera doesn't like something about this, so if we
  // think we're using Opera, don't even try
  var is_opera = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("opera") != -1);
  if (is_opera)
    return;

  // put a try/catch block around the whole thing, just in case
  try {
    if (!document.getElementById(iFrameDivID)) {

      var newNode = document.createElement("iFrame");
      newNode.setAttribute("id", iFrameDivID);
      newNode.setAttribute("src", "javascript:false;");
      newNode.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
      newNode.setAttribute ("frameborder", "0");
      document.body.appendChild(newNode);
    }

    if (!pickerDiv)
      pickerDiv = document.getElementById(datePickerDivID);
    if (!iFrameDiv)
      iFrameDiv = document.getElementById(iFrameDivID);

    try {
      iFrameDiv.style.position = "absolute";
      iFrameDiv.style.width = pickerDiv.offsetWidth;
      iFrameDiv.style.height = pickerDiv.offsetHeight ;
      iFrameDiv.style.top = pickerDiv.style.top;
      iFrameDiv.style.left = pickerDiv.style.left;
      iFrameDiv.style.zIndex = pickerDiv.style.zIndex - 1;
      iFrameDiv.style.visibility = pickerDiv.style.visibility ;
      iFrameDiv.style.display = pickerDiv.style.display;
    } catch(e) {
    }

  } catch (ee) {
  }

}
```

When I tested in firbug it is giving me the error `TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function` 
I've included the files reuired i.e. jquery1.9.1 and datepicker .js, but still it's not working. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I suggest to use jsfiddle for kind of question. BTW its working with jquery UI 1.9.2 library http://jsfiddle.net/aKr2J/

Comment: I know it can be trivial but have you added the jquery-ui library?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just working perfectly! Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aKr2J/).

You just missed to include jquery-ui

Try including : `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` in you `<head>` tag.

**UPDATE:** The fiddle is by *@Safiuddin*